# Regex to find TLD from Domain name

Tags: android, regex

I am getting a full domain name.. What i want is just to get the domain **TLD** form that name.
I have looked for alot patterns but could not find any to get TLD from Domain Name.
For example: www.foo.co.uk & www.foo.org etc
I jusr want **.co.uk** & **.org** out of it.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android provides the [`Patterns.TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN) Pattern for this situation. You can use it like you would use any other [`Pattern`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

From the [`Pattern`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation:

```
// Direct use of Pattern:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Hello, (\\S+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while (m.find()) { // Find each match in turn
    String name = m.group(1); // Access a submatch groupthis.
}
```

Where you (obviously) need to set `p` to `Patterns.TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN` to check for the TLDs:

```
Pattern p = Patterns.TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN;
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputURLString);
```

Comment: but how to use it?? i am not getting any way..
I am new to android

Comment: He answered this already  but you can use the following link to read the reference guide http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html